# REST API: Существует ли стандарт для разделителя в названии ресурса?

Tags: api, rest

Как правильнее?

`/api/game_sessions`

или

`/api/game-sessions`

Ни в одном из официальных документов на нашел никаких упоминаний, какой разделитель предпочтительнее.

Здесь нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778203/are-there-any-naming-convention-guidelines-for-rest-apis), что

> The REST API for Dropbox, Twitter, Google Web Services and Facebook all uses underscores.

Я тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту.

Существует ли на эту тему какой-либо стандарт? Или же с точки зрения стандартов разницы нет?

Comment: я бы использовал так `/api/game_sessions`

Comment: Я бы тоже, но никак не могу найти стандарт на эту тему

Comment: так используйте тогда так, как вам нравится

Comment: Как это часто бывает, We're at war, We're at Holy War! Обсуждаем с коллегами, как правильнее :)

Comment: StackOverflow [использует](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) kebab-case.

Comment: именование пути согласно REST-методологии имеет множество оговорок, но там ничего не говорится об конкретном стиле - верблюжья нотация, нижнее подчеркивание, дефисы (тем более, что w3-стандарт чувствителен к регистру path-части url). значит эта проблема лежит на разработчике.  главное, чтобы ваш api был понятным и однообразным для конечного пользователя. а стили именования ресурсов у многих известных api разнятся. например, google api часто использует camelCase, у твиттера видел дефисы, фейсбук использует underscores. к сожалению, ваш вопрос закрыт для ответов, не могу привести примеры

Comment: не понимаю, почему закрыт вопрос из-за "порождения дискуссий", полезная тема и можно однозначно ответить. Попробуйте переименовать в "Можно использовать camelCase в REST-url?"

Comment: Вопрос открыли, но не факт, что Ваш ответ подойдет. Насколько я понял, Вы утверждаете, что ответ "нет". Можете ли Вы это подтвердить пруфами?